# How to get reference to an element of a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, reference, stdtuple

You can get the value of the `n`th element of an `std::tuple` using `std::get<n>(tuple)`. But I need to pass one element of that tuple as reference to a function.

How do I get the reference to an element of a `std::tuple`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) returns a reference(either const or non-const), so this works:

```
void fun(int &a) {
    a = 15;
}

void test() {
    std::tuple<int, char> foo{ 12, 'a' };
    fun(std::get<0>(foo));
}
```

Demo [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Ye3QO$2).

Comment: The demo link doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

`get` returns a reference, rvalue reference or const reference depending on the type of its argument.