# How do I overloading tuple in map [] operator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, operator-overloading

Here is my Code...

```
class Obj
{
public : 
    int iNum = 100;
};

map<string, tuple<int,Obj*>> maplist;
auto pObj = new Obj();
auto pObj1 = new Obj();
maplist["hi"] = make_tuple( 100, pObj );
cout << maplist["hi"].first << endl; // Error !
cout << maplist["hi"].second << endl; // Error !
```

Error Msg : E0135 has no member

I want to program properties( .first, .second, third ... ). How can I operator overloading ? What can I do with it ? Is []operator in map ? Or Add properties in tuple ?

Comment: [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is *not* like `std::pair`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835762/how-to-get-reference-to-an-element-of-a-stdtuple

Comment: I know already not like std::pair. But I want to program like pair. I program to add properties as many as tuple elements.count. How do I do ? Is not possible ?

Comment: Did you read the linked reference? Did you check [its example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple#Example)? The example shows you three ways to get the "elements" from a tuple. Also, basic logic thinking should have you understand that you can't have members like `first` and `second` for a data-type without (theoretical) limits on the number of values it can store.

Comment: Your link example is very useful. But can't you do with tuple overloading ?

Comment: Of course you can, but then you first need to get the data from the tuple. Which is what seems to be your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get reference to an element of a std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835762/how-to-get-reference-to-an-element-of-a-stdtuple)